# Answer not deleted after six "Recommend Deletion"

Tags: discussion, review, answers, deletion, low-quality-posts

> **Update: answer deleted**

This is my third question about the main site's LQ review.

In [this review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/1152968), six users (including me) has "recommended deletion".  From [When is a post removed from a review queue?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/164288) on Meta.SE, it's clear that the 6<sup>th</sup> "Recommend Deletion" vote has terminated this review.

Nonetheless, I wonder why this link-only answer has *not* yet been deleted.  This post has *never* been edited, so we are seeing it as what it was during the review.

Thanks for any comments and answers.

Comment: The answer under review is posted at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2844894/what-are-the-moments-of-the-riemann-zeta-function

Comment: I will add link to the [revision history](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3111137/revisions) and [the timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3111137/timeline).

Comment: The linked Answer under review has now been deleted.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks for update.  I've edited the question body to make this clearer for others.

Comment: I like how this post has 6 upvotes.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Because the post has a positive score.

According to Shog9's answer on [Is “recommend deletion” secretly a vote to delete?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/145292)

> Yes, a sufficient number of delete recommendations (currently 6 on most sites, 4 on Stack Overflow) will cause the post to be **deleted immediately, provided it has zero or negative score**. (If it has a positive score, it will raise an automatic moderator flag instead.)
>
> <sup>(Emphasis mine)</sup>

Comment: Thanks Andrew for answer.

Comment: This leads to the question why it's impossible to vote from the review screen.  As this shows, reviewers should strongly consider downvoting when they recommend deletion, but this requires several other clicks.

Comment: @CarlMummert I've posted your suggestion on [Meta.SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/323938/259305) since it's about the engine that powers the whole SE network.